# Keyboard input without repeat delay

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I'm trying to solve a problem where I got a character moving around on a 2D-plane using the WASD-keys. However when I hold a button the code writes once then makes a delay and then writes nonstop.

How to remove this delay? I've seen some solutions using after() with canvas() but not sure how to apply this to a label() using "text=".

Thanks for any ideas!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

coordinates = {
    "x1y1": "", "x2y1": "", "x3y1": "", "x4y1": "", "x5y1": "", "x6y1": "", "x7y1": "", "x8y1": "", "x9y1": "",
    "x1y2": "", "x2y2": "", "x3y2": "", "x4y2": "", "x5y2": "", "x6y2": "", "x7y2": "", "x8y2": "", "x9y2": "",
    "x1y3": "", "x2y3": "", "x3y3": "", "x4y3": "", "x5y3": "", "x6y3": "", "x7y3": "", "x8y3": "", "x9y3": "",
    "x1y4": "", "x2y4": "", "x3y4": "", "x4y4": "", "x5y4": "", "x6y4": "", "x7y4": "", "x8y4": "", "x9y4": "",
    "x1y5": "", "x2y5": "", "x3y5": "", "x4y5": "", "x5y5": "", "x6y5": "", "x7y5": "", "x8y5": "", "x9y5": "",
    "x1y6": "", "x2y6": "", "x3y6": "", "x4y6": "", "x5y6": "", "x6y6": "", "x7y6": "", "x8y6": "", "x9y6": "",
    "x1y7": "", "x2y7": "", "x3y7": "", "x4y7": "", "x5y7": "", "x6y7": "", "x7y7": "", "x8y7": "", "x9y7": "",
    "x1y8": "", "x2y8": "", "x3y8": "", "x4y8": "", "x5y8": "", "x6y8": "", "x7y8": "", "x8y8": "", "x9y8": "",
    "x1y9": "", "x2y9": "", "x3y9": "", "x4y9": "", "x5y9": "", "x6y9": "", "x7y9": "", "x8y9": "", "x9y9": "",
    
}


#Player starting position
player_x = 5
player_y = 5


#Onpress update player X/Y positions and make sure they don't exceed coordinate system
def keypress_w(event):
    global player_y
    player_y -= 1
    if player_y < 1:
        player_y += 1
    update_world()

def keypress_a(event):
    global player_x
    player_x -= 1
    if player_x < 1:
        player_x += 1
    update_world()

def keypress_d(event):
    global player_x
    player_x += 1
    if player_x > 9:
         player_x -= 1
    update_world()

def keypress_s(event):
    global player_y
    player_y += 1
    if player_y > 9:
        player_y -= 1
    update_world()
    
def keypress_esc(event):
    sys.exit()

def update_world():
    #Create string with player coordinates and input into dictionary
    player_xy = "x", player_x, "y", player_y
    player_coord = ''.join(map(str, player_xy))

    #Update previous player tile to map tile
    coord_keys = coordinates.keys()
    for coords in coord_keys:
        if coords == player_coord:
            coordinates[player_coord] = '€'
        else:
            coordinates[coords] = ' '

    #Print map
    width = 9
    coord_values = coordinates.values()
    i=0
    world=""

    for item in coord_values:
        world = world + item + " "
        i += 1
        if i % width == 0:
            world = world[:-1] + '\n'

    world = world[:-1]

    #refresh the label that displays the world
    world_label.place(x=220,y=100)
    world_label.configure(font=("Courier", 24), text=world, bg="white")



root = Tk() #Create window

world_label = Label() #Create World Label widget
world_label.pack()
update_world() #Function update_world


#Sends pressed key values to functions keypress_"x"
root.bind("<w>", keypress_w)
root.bind("<a>", keypress_a)
root.bind("<s>", keypress_s)
root.bind("<d>", keypress_d)
root.bind("<Escape>", keypress_esc) 



root.geometry("800x600") #Size of window 
root.title('Game 0.1') #Title of window 
root.mainloop() #
```

Comment: It is a system configuration on keyboard device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use timer method `root.after(delay, func)` to trigger function to simulate keyboard repeat.

New demo code for you.
It work for both key pressed at the same time.

```py
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

class Root(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=width, height=height, bg='green')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')
        self.radius = 20
        self.delay = 20
        self.step = 5
        self.x = width // 2
        self.y = height // 2
        self.press_left  = False
        self.press_right = False
        self.press_up    = False
        self.press_down  = False
        self.ball = None
        self.draw_ball()
        self.binding()

    def draw_ball(self):
        if self.ball:
            self.canvas.delete(self.ball)
        self.ball = self.canvas.create_oval(self.x - self.radius, self.y - self.radius,
            self.x + self.radius, self.y + self.radius, fill='white')
        self.canvas.update()

    def binding(self):
        self.bind("<KeyPress-a>",   self.left_down)
        self.bind("<KeyPress-d>",   self.right_down)
        self.bind("<KeyPress-w>",   self.up_down)
        self.bind("<KeyPress-s>",   self.down_down)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease-a>", self.left_up)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease-d>", self.right_up)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease-w>", self.up_up)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease-s>", self.down_up)
        self.bind("<Escape>",       self.escape)

    def left_down(self, event):
        def left():
            if self.press_left:
                if self.x >= self.radius + self.step:
                    self.x -= self.step
                    self.draw_ball()
                self.after(self.delay, left)
            else:
                self.bind("<KeyPress-a>", self.left_down)
        self.unbind("<KeyPress-a>")
        self.press_left = True
        left()

    def left_up(self, event):
        self.press_left = False

    def right_down(self, event):
        def right():
            if self.press_right:
                if self.x <= self.width - self.radius - self.step:
                    self.x += self.step
                    self.draw_ball()
                self.after(self.delay, right)
            else:
                self.bind("<KeyPress-d>", self.right_down)
        self.unbind("<KeyPress-d>")
        self.press_right = True
        right()

    def right_up(self, event):
        self.press_right = False

    def up_down(self, event):
        def up():
            if self.press_up:
                if self.y >= self.radius + self.step:
                    self.y -= self.step
                    self.draw_ball()
                self.after(self.delay, up)
            else:
                self.bind("<KeyPress-w>", self.up_down)
        self.unbind("<KeyPress-w>")
        self.press_up = True
        up()

    def up_up(self, event):
        self.press_up = False

    def down_down(self, event):
        def down():
            if self.press_down:
                if self.y <= self.height - self.radius - self.step:
                    self.y += self.step
                    self.draw_ball()
                self.after(self.delay, down)
            else:
                self.bind("<KeyPress-s>", self.down_down)
        self.unbind("<KeyPress-s>")
        self.press_down = True
        down()

    def down_up(self, event):
        self.press_down = False

    def escape(self, event):
        root.destroy()

root = Root("Game 0.1", 800, 600)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll play around with this and try to implement into my code!